# How to have both Right and Left Hand side on O365 MasterPage

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, master-page

I have an O365 site collection. I want to modify my master page so that I have a fixed left hand sidebar (navigation), but then also a right hand bar which has fixed web parts in it.

[image: Here is what it will look like on every page.]

Is this even possible? 
There is so much content about master pages and after an hours' investigation I just want a recommendation on where to start, if this is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. First you start with a html layout using div. Test this in the browser (You can use border to make sure the boxes are appearing as required).

Once this is done you can use SharePoint design manager and upload the html file. This will get converted to a SharePoint master page.

Then use SharePoint designer and go to the master pages folder, then edit the file.

Next open SharePoint design manager in IE and generated snippets for webpart zones. Copy the the code and switch to SPD, paste those inside the div zones you have created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am playing with HTML master page at the moment. Do you know where can I get more information about the bits that start with "<SPM:"    on the master page? Are they all auto-generated or will I need to write those as well ?

Comment: You can use snippet manager and generate code.. and paste it into your master page.. no need to make any modifications to those.... You can generate code for top navigation, left navigation etc..